# Equivalence of two optimization problems involving norms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

In a famous paper of Hastie *et al.*, the authors have been using the following two optimization problems ($P1$ and $P2$) in $\beta$ interchangeably:

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \lVert \beta \rVert_1\\ \text{subject to} & \lVert X^T(y - X\beta) \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lambda\end{array} \tag{P1}$$

and

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \lVert X^T(y - X\beta) \rVert_{\infty}\\ \text{subject to} & \lVert \beta \rVert_{1} \leq s\end{array} \tag{P2}$$

Can someone please justify the equivalence between the two problems ($P1$ and $P2$) and how can one obtain $s$ from $\lambda$ for given problem $P1$ and vice-versa?

Comment: Why not provide a link to the paper? DOI, please.

Answer (score 1):

A constrained optimization problem like

$\min_x f(x)$ such that $g(x)\leq k_1$

is equivalent (through proper choice of the regularization parameter $k_2$) to

$\min_x f(x) + k_2 g(x)$

So, in some sense, both of the problems you are looking at are equivalent to

$\min_\beta c_1\|X^T(y-X\beta)\|_\infty + c_2\|\beta\|_1$

for proper choice of $c_1$ and $c_2$, given that the choices of $s$ and $\lambda$ are coherent. What I mean by coherence is that the choice of $s$ or $\lambda$ dictates what constant you get for the regularizer when you convert from a contrained problem to a regularized problem. For example, if $s$ was 0 then the regularizing constant would be $\infty$.

Comment: Any idea how can we get relevant parameter $s$ from $\lambda$ to ensure the equivalence of $P1$ and $P2$?

Comment: Any reference for it would also be fine.

Comment: This thread explains it better than I did. Indeed, it's just an instance of Lagrange multipliers.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816231/regularization-versus-inequality-constraint

Comment: @griffith in general, there is no way to retrieve $s$ from $\lambda$, or vice versa. These two problems are equivalent in the sense that they trace out the same tradeoff curve with, say, $\|\beta\|_1$ on one axis and $\|X^T(y-X\beta)\|_\infty$ on the other. They are not equivalent in any stronger sense.